# Routing and switching

Tags: cisco, routing

Can L2 ping L4? From [cisco routing and switching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aYb0.png)

Which of the following statements are correct about the network?

- There are 3 networks in the topology
- The routers cannot send packets between each other
- Switches are configured with correct IP address
- L1 and L2 do not have correct IP addresses

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 networks in the topology. 193.168.10.x , 1.6.10.x and 173.16.24.x